# File ended while scanning use of \beamer@collect@@body

Tags: beamer, errors

I have this error: File ended while scanning use of \beamer@collect@@body.

I do not know why.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
\beamersetuncovermixins{\opaqueness<1>{25}}{\opaqueness<2->{15}}
\begin{document}
    \title{Internet und soziale Medien}  
    \author{José Kress}
    \date{\today} 

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame} 

\section{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
\subsection{Aufbau}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Zwei Bl\"ocke}

\begin{block}{Erster Teil}
    Artikel: Shelley Boulianne (2015). "Social media use and participation: a metaanalysis of current research" 
\end{block}

\begin{exampleblock}{Zweiter Teil}
    Eigene Forschung 
\end{exampleblock}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Inhaltsverzeichnis}\tableofcontents
\end{frame} 


\section{Zum Artikel} 
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Zum Artikel} 
"Social media use and participation: a metaanalysis of current research"
Shelley Boulianne (2015) 
\end{frame}

\subsection{Einf\"uhrung}
\begin{frame} 
Soziale online Netzwerke sind ein relatives neues Phänomen. 
Immer gr\"ossere Dimensionen (8% 2005 -> 33% 2008; USA) 
Facebook Users: 35% -> 72% 2013 
Arabische Fr\"uhling oder Obamas politische Kampagne: Welchen Effekt haben die sozialen Medien auf politische Partizipation? 
\end{frame}

\subsection{Einf\"uhrung}
\begin{frame} 
Metaanalyse von 36 Studien (mit 170 Effekten) über die Beziehung zwischen soziale Medien und Partizipation. 
\end{frame}

\subsection{Effekte der sozialen Medien}
\begin{frame} 
Theorie 1: Facebook als Informationsanbieter
Ungefähr die H\"alfte der Facebook Users informieren sich über Aktualit\"at durch Facebook. 
Die meisten Informationen die Facebook Users konsumieren zurück gehören zu ihrem sozialen Netzwerk. 
Die Users sind an mobilisierender Information ausgesetzt ohne diese zu Suchen. 
Diese Informationen sind Einflussreicher, da diese aus einer vertrauensvolle Beziehung entsteht. 
Eine Verbreitung von politischen Informationen ermöglicht eine höhere Partizipation.  
\end{frame}
\subsection{Effekte der sozialen Medien}
\begin{frame} 
Theorie 2: Soziale Medien schaffen soziale Netzwerke. 
3 Fokus:
Auf die grösse des Netzwerkes (zB bei Unterschriftensammlungen) 
Auf die sozialen Bindungen zwischen Gruppen, Organisationen und Aktivisten. (zB Freiwilligenarbeit)
Auf die Diffusion durch Peer Gruppen. (zB wie politische Meinungen durch Facebookfreunde beeinflusst werden können.    
\end{frame}

\subsection{Methoden}
\begin{frame} 
Mit der Metaanalyse ist es möglich herauszufinden welche dieser Theorien stärker ist. 
Es ist auch möglich herauszufinden ob der Effekt der sozialen Medien auf der ganzen Gesellschaft zu sehen ist oder eher nur auf einzelne Gruppen und in unterschiedlichen politischen Systeme.  
\end{frame}

\subsection{Methoden}
\begin{frame} 
Es wurden für diese Metaanalyse soziale Onlinenetzwerke (Facebook, Twitter, YouTube, usw.) 
Quantitative Verhaltensstudien (Wählen, demonstrieren, Freiwilligenarbeit, usw.)
14 Studien: generelle Population (50 Schätzer über die Beziehung zwischen soziale Medien und Partizipation). 
13 Studien: Studenten (82 Schätzer über die Beziehung zwischen soziale Medien und Partizipation).
Nur 4 Studien: vor 2008 durchgeführt. 
6 Studien: Paneldesign.    
\end{frame}

\subsection{Ergebnisse}
\begin{frame} 
Es ist unklar ob es sich um Effekte oder blosse Korrelationen handelt (da die meisten der benutzten Studien ihre Estimationen aus cross-sectional surveys sich ergeben haben. 
Es wird auf die Prozentsätze von positiven Koeffizienten und statistische Signifikanz (.05) fokussiert (da die Methoden zwischen den Studien variieren).   
\end{frame}

\subsection{Ergebnisse} 
\begin{frame}[plain]
\frametitle{Ergebnisse}
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{"C:/Users/josek/Desktop/UNI/Politische Einstellungen/tabelle1"}
    \caption{Die Beziehung zwischen soziale Medien und Partizipation ist positiv}
    \label{fig:tabelle1}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Ergebnisse} 
\begin{frame}[plain]
\frametitle{Ergebnisse}
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{"C:/Users/josek/Desktop/UNI/Politische Einstellungen/tabelle2"}
    \caption{Hier wird der Fokus der Studien noch genauer angeschaut. 
        Beziehung zwischen soziale Medien und Wahlkampagnen ist schwach. 
        Wenn Protest als Mass der Partizipation benutzt wird haben wir mehr Positive Effekte, aber weniger Statistische Signifikanz.}
    \label{fig:tabelle2}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Ergebnisse}
\begin{frame} 
Das heisst, den Fokus auf Wahlkampagnen Aktivit\"aten, Panel Daten, die gr\"osse des Samples und die generelle Population sind die eher konsistenten Pr\"adiktoren.    
\end{frame}

\subsection{Ergebnisse} 
\begin{frame}[plain]
\frametitle{Ergebnisse}
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{"C:/Users/josek/Desktop/UNI/Politische Einstellungen/tabelle 3"}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:tabelle 3}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Can somebody help me? Thanks!

Comment: I guess is that this is because `\begin{frame}\frametitle{Zwei Bl\"ocke}` has no `\end{frame}`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: In your Einf\"uhrung you forgot to escape the %. Whatever follows will be interpretated as comment and ignored (not your question but you might find it helpful).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot one `\end{frame}`  in the section "Inhaltsverzeichnis". I marked the added `\end{frame}` with `% <---------------`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
\beamersetuncovermixins{\opaqueness<1>{25}}{\opaqueness<2->{15}}
\begin{document}
    \title{Internet und soziale Medien}  
    \author{José Kress}
    \date{\today} 

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame} 

\section{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
\subsection{Aufbau}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Zwei Bl\"ocke}

\begin{block}{Erster Teil}
    Artikel: Shelley Boulianne (2015). "Social media use and participation: a metaanalysis of current research" 
\end{block}

\begin{exampleblock}{Zweiter Teil}
    Eigene Forschung 
\end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}% <---------------

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Inhaltsverzeichnis}\tableofcontents
\end{frame} 


\section{Zum Artikel} 
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Zum Artikel} 
"Social media use and participation: a metaanalysis of current research"
Shelley Boulianne (2015) 
\end{frame}

\subsection{Einf\"uhrung}
\begin{frame} 
Soziale online Netzwerke sind ein relatives neues Phänomen. 
Immer gr\"ossere Dimensionen (8% 2005 -> 33% 2008; USA) 
Facebook Users: 35% -> 72% 2013 
Arabische Fr\"uhling oder Obamas politische Kampagne: Welchen Effekt haben die sozialen Medien auf politische Partizipation? 
\end{frame}

\subsection{Einf\"uhrung}
\begin{frame} 
Metaanalyse von 36 Studien (mit 170 Effekten) über die Beziehung zwischen soziale Medien und Partizipation. 
\end{frame}

\subsection{Effekte der sozialen Medien}
\begin{frame} 
Theorie 1: Facebook als Informationsanbieter
Ungefähr die H\"alfte der Facebook Users informieren sich über Aktualit\"at durch Facebook. 
Die meisten Informationen die Facebook Users konsumieren zurück gehören zu ihrem sozialen Netzwerk. 
Die Users sind an mobilisierender Information ausgesetzt ohne diese zu Suchen. 
Diese Informationen sind Einflussreicher, da diese aus einer vertrauensvolle Beziehung entsteht. 
Eine Verbreitung von politischen Informationen ermöglicht eine höhere Partizipation.  
\end{frame}
\subsection{Effekte der sozialen Medien}
\begin{frame} 
Theorie 2: Soziale Medien schaffen soziale Netzwerke. 
3 Fokus:
Auf die grösse des Netzwerkes (zB bei Unterschriftensammlungen) 
Auf die sozialen Bindungen zwischen Gruppen, Organisationen und Aktivisten. (zB Freiwilligenarbeit)
Auf die Diffusion durch Peer Gruppen. (zB wie politische Meinungen durch Facebookfreunde beeinflusst werden können.    
\end{frame}

\subsection{Methoden}
\begin{frame} 
Mit der Metaanalyse ist es möglich herauszufinden welche dieser Theorien stärker ist. 
Es ist auch möglich herauszufinden ob der Effekt der sozialen Medien auf der ganzen Gesellschaft zu sehen ist oder eher nur auf einzelne Gruppen und in unterschiedlichen politischen Systeme.  
\end{frame}

\subsection{Methoden}
\begin{frame} 
Es wurden für diese Metaanalyse soziale Onlinenetzwerke (Facebook, Twitter, YouTube, usw.) 
Quantitative Verhaltensstudien (Wählen, demonstrieren, Freiwilligenarbeit, usw.)
14 Studien: generelle Population (50 Schätzer über die Beziehung zwischen soziale Medien und Partizipation). 
13 Studien: Studenten (82 Schätzer über die Beziehung zwischen soziale Medien und Partizipation).
Nur 4 Studien: vor 2008 durchgeführt. 
6 Studien: Paneldesign.    
\end{frame}

\subsection{Ergebnisse}
\begin{frame} 
Es ist unklar ob es sich um Effekte oder blosse Korrelationen handelt (da die meisten der benutzten Studien ihre Estimationen aus cross-sectional surveys sich ergeben haben. 
Es wird auf die Prozentsätze von positiven Koeffizienten und statistische Signifikanz (.05) fokussiert (da die Methoden zwischen den Studien variieren).   
\end{frame}

\subsection{Ergebnisse} 
\begin{frame}[plain]
\frametitle{Ergebnisse}
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{"C:/Users/josek/Desktop/UNI/Politische Einstellungen/tabelle1"}
    \caption{Die Beziehung zwischen soziale Medien und Partizipation ist positiv}
    \label{fig:tabelle1}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Ergebnisse} 
\begin{frame}[plain]
\frametitle{Ergebnisse}
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{"C:/Users/josek/Desktop/UNI/Politische Einstellungen/tabelle2"}
    \caption{Hier wird der Fokus der Studien noch genauer angeschaut. 
        Beziehung zwischen soziale Medien und Wahlkampagnen ist schwach. 
        Wenn Protest als Mass der Partizipation benutzt wird haben wir mehr Positive Effekte, aber weniger Statistische Signifikanz.}
    \label{fig:tabelle2}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Ergebnisse}
\begin{frame} 
Das heisst, den Fokus auf Wahlkampagnen Aktivit\"aten, Panel Daten, die gr\"osse des Samples und die generelle Population sind die eher konsistenten Pr\"adiktoren.    
\end{frame}

\subsection{Ergebnisse} 
\begin{frame}[plain]
\frametitle{Ergebnisse}
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{"C:/Users/josek/Desktop/UNI/Politische Einstellungen/tabelle 3"}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:tabelle 3}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: @Jos you might accept my answer then. Please note for the future, that you should not use local files in minimal working examples [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/117050) you provide on this site, instead for images use `example-image` which should be contained in most LaTeX installations.